# Unreachable Statement when trying to run program

Tags: java

I get the error message `unreachable statement` when I try to compile this bit of code on the line `return oocc2.encrypt(input);`:

```
  public String decrypt(String input) {
        OOCaesarCipher oocc1 = new OOCaesarCipher(26-mainKey1);
        OOCaesarCipher oocc2 = new OOCaesarCipher(26-mainKey2);
        return oocc1.encrypt(input);
        return oocc2.encrypt(input);

    }
```

I think it's because I have a second return statement, but I don't know how else to write this method with two key integers. Originally this method was like this in another class.

```
public String decrypt(String input) {
        OOCaesarCipher oocc1 = new OOCaesarCipher(26-mainKey1);
        return oocc1.encrypt(input);
        }
```

Can someone please share his/her knowledge of how to write a better method so that it compiles without an error.
 I've included the whole code in case there's need for referencing.

```
import edu.duke.*;

public class CaesarCipherTwoKeys {
    private String alphabetLower;
    private String alphabetUpper;
    private String shiftedAlphabetLower1;
    private String shiftedAlphabetUpper1;
    private String shiftedAlphabetLower2;
    private String shiftedAlphabetUpper2;
    private int mainKey1;
    private int mainKey2;
    public CaesarCipherTwoKeys(int key1, int key2) {
        alphabetLower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        alphabetUpper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        shiftedAlphabetLower1 = alphabetLower.substring(key1) + alphabetLower.substring(0,key1);
        shiftedAlphabetUpper1 = alphabetUpper.substring(key1) + alphabetUpper.substring(0,key1);
        shiftedAlphabetLower2 = alphabetLower.substring(key2) + alphabetLower.substring(0,key2);
        shiftedAlphabetUpper2 = alphabetUpper.substring(key2) + alphabetUpper.substring(0,key2);
        mainKey1 = key1;
        mainKey2 = key2;
    }
    public String encrypt(String input) {
        StringBuilder encryptedInput = new StringBuilder(input);
        OOCaesarCipher oocc1 = new OOCaesarCipher(mainKey1);
        OOCaesarCipher oocc2 = new OOCaesarCipher(mainKey2);

        for (int index=0; index < input.length(); index++) {
            if (index % 2 == 0 || index == 0) {
                encryptedInput.replace(index,index+1,oocc1.encrypt(input.substring(index,index+1)));
            }
            else {
                encryptedInput.replace(index,index+1,oocc2.encrypt(input.substring(index,index+1)));
            }
        }
        return encryptedInput.toString();
    }
    public String decrypt(String input) {
        OOCaesarCipher oocc1 = new OOCaesarCipher(26-mainKey1);
        OOCaesarCipher oocc2 = new OOCaesarCipher(26-mainKey2);
        return oocc1.encrypt(input);
        return oocc2.encrypt(input);

    }
}
```

And here's the OOCC code which I'm using as an example for writing this one:

```
import edu.duke.*;


public class OOCaesarCipher {
    private String alphabetLower;
    private String alphabetUpper;
    private String shiftedAlphabetLower;
    private String shiftedAlphabetUpper;
    private int mainKey;
    public OOCaesarCipher(int key) {
        alphabetLower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        alphabetUpper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        shiftedAlphabetLower = alphabetLower.substring(key) + alphabetLower.substring(0,key);
        shiftedAlphabetUpper = alphabetUpper.substring(key) + alphabetUpper.substring(0,key);
        mainKey = key;
    }
    public String encrypt(String input) {
        StringBuilder encrypted = new StringBuilder(input);
        for (int index=0; index < encrypted.length(); index++) {
            Character currChar = encrypted.charAt(index);
            int currentIndex = 0;

            if (Character.isLowerCase(currChar)) {
                currentIndex = alphabetLower.indexOf(currChar);
            }
            else {
                currentIndex = alphabetUpper.indexOf(currChar);
            }

            if (currentIndex != -1 && Character.isLowerCase(currChar)) {
                char newChar = shiftedAlphabetLower.charAt(currentIndex);
                encrypted.setCharAt(index, newChar);
            }
            else if (currentIndex != -1) {
                char newChar = shiftedAlphabetUpper.charAt(currentIndex);
                encrypted.setCharAt(index, newChar);
            }
        }
        return encrypted.toString();
    }
    public String decrypt(String input) {
        OOCaesarCipher oocc = new OOCaesarCipher(26-mainKey);
        return oocc.encrypt(input);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a string array like so:

```
public String[] decrypt(String input) {

    String[] oocc1And2 = new String[2];
    OOCaesarCipher oocc1 = new OOCaesarCipher(26-mainKey1);
    OOCaesarCipher oocc2 = new OOCaesarCipher(26-mainKey2);

    oocc1And2[0] = oocc1.encrypt(input);
    oocc1And2[1] = oocc2.encrypt(input);
    return oocc1And2;

 }
```

Comment: This results in an array error `array dimension missing`

Comment: try this replacement String[] oocc1And2 = new String[2];

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with below code

```
return oocc1.encrypt(input);
return oocc2.encrypt(input);
```

You cannot have any statement after `return statement` in java, compiler cannot understand as how to run.

If you need to return two values, create a `Map` add values to it and then return,

or make a `POJO`, set values then return...

you might need to modify the method,

Below is taking the `input` as `String input`.
Also try adding one more input maybe, for keys, values can come as `26-mainKey1` or `26-mainKey2`

```
public String decrypt(String input) {
        OOCaesarCipher oocc1 = new OOCaesarCipher(26-mainKey1);
        return oocc1.encrypt(input);
        }
```

Comment: We haven't learned how to use `Map` yet in our class. What is a `POJO`?

Comment: @user5745776 Plain Old Java Object - There was a need for a term to describe an object that does not have anything special about it.

Comment: How do you use a `POJO`?